# Django-- SyncDB and South Migrations failing due to Bad MySQL Connection

Tags: mysql, django, django-south

When I try to run the syncdb, it raises the following error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

Similar issues are cropping up for running South Migrations.  The odd thing here is that I am able to run ./manage.py shell and lookup model objects without any issues.  It seems that my settings file database configuration is working in that instance.

Why would syncdb/migrate fail in this case while shell works?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that that user doesn't have enough access needed for syncdb, whereas they have sufficient access to access the models.

Your best bet would be to look at the root privileges (which I would think should be everything) and see if something needs to be changed.  You also might consider creating a new user and giving them the necessary rights so that you don't increase the chance of changing the root user settings.